# How can I initialise struct's map field using reflection

Tags: go

How can I initialise struct's map field using reflection ?

Sample code that panics and I want to make it work ([Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vPp6QcMmwiK)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Names map[string]string
}

func main() {
    var u interface{} = User{}
    names := make(map[string]string)
    names["test"] = "test"

    v := reflect.ValueOf(u)
    n := reflect.ValueOf(names)

    field := v.FieldByName("Names")
    field.Set(n)

    fmt.Println(v.Interface())
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

```
panic: reflect: reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable using unaddressable value

goroutine 1 [running]:
reflect.flag.mustBeAssignableSlow(0x15, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:247 +0x180
reflect.flag.mustBeAssignable(...)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:234
reflect.Value.Set(0x101ec0, 0x0, 0x15, 0x101ec0, 0x43e280, 0x15)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:1531 +0x40
main.main()
    /tmp/sandbox776916734/prog.go:21 +0x200
```

Comment: Use pointers. Read https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/eiVmRsvw98E

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type User struct {
    Names map[string]string
}

func main() {
    var u interface{} = &User{} // the key is here
    names := make(map[string]string)
    names["test"] = "test"

    v := reflect.ValueOf(u)
    n := reflect.ValueOf(names)

    field := v.Elem().FieldByName("Names")
    field.Set(n)

    fmt.Println(v.Interface())
    fmt.Println(u)
}
```

Comment: but that is the thing you want to work it for both cases i suppose. its been some time since i asked. but lets assume you dont know the input its interface{} so could be value or a pointer